# Equivalent of Swift's subtractingReportingOverflow in Kotlin?

Tags: swift, kotlin, code-conversion

What would be the Kotlin equivalent of detecting overflow as is done in Swift's `subtractingReportingOverflow`?

For instance, the following in Swift yields `shiftValue` of `7212078330627782743`  and `overflow` of `true` :

```swift
var someValue = 7212078330627782743
let shiftSize = 5
let shiftedValue = (someValue << shiftSize).subtractingReportingOverflow(someValue)

print("shiftedValue: \(shiftedValue.partialValue)") //yields 7212078330627782743
print("overflow: \(shiftedValue.overflow)") //yields true
```

I've tried calculating the overflow a couple of ways in Kotlin but I don't get the same results:

```kotlin
fun isOverflow1(shiftedValue: Long):Boolean {
    return shiftedValue < 0
}

fun isOverflow2(shiftedValue: Long):Boolean { 
    return shiftedValue > Int.MIN_VALUE && shiftedValue < Int.MAX_VALUE) {
}

val someValue = 7212078330627782743
val shiftedValue: Long = (someValue shl shiftSize) - someValue
val overflow = isOverflow1(shiftedValue)  // isOverflow2(shiftedValue)

println("overflow: $overflow") // yields false regardless of isOverflow1() or isOverflow2()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest would be [`Math.subtractExact`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#subtractExact(int,int)), for Kotlin JVM only. This method "reports overflow" by throwing an `ArithmeticException`. You can use this if whatever you are doing should "fail" in the case of an overflow.

```
Math.subtractExact(someValue shl shiftSize, someValue)
```

If you want to do something else when it overflows, I would not catch the exception and use it as a control flow mechanism. I suggest writing your own method, based on the [implementation of `subtractExact`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Math.java#L968).

```
infix fun Long.subtractReportingOverflow(other: Long): Pair<Long, Boolean> {
    val r = this - other
    return r to ((this xor other) and (this xor r) < 0)
}
```

That said, this allocates a new `Pair` on the heap every time, and might affect GC if you use this often.

Comment: Could you return an `Optional<Long>` instead? Though I guess that also has an allocation as well

Comment: @Alexander yeah, also OP might still want to know the subtraction result even when an overflow did occur.